# Secure Folder Share, Without Cloud, or Forced Sync! That supports Thumbnail Previews

Tags: windows, file-management, sharing

I am trying to find a P2P Folder sharing Program, Similar to FTP but with the Client and Server Running together. However everything seems to be Cloud and Auto Sync.

### Requirements:

Direct File Transfers
Client must also Be a Server
Image Thumbnail Previews
Full Folder View for Browsing Files (no Forced Tree View)

Absolutely No AutoSync (Aside From Thumbnails).
Absolutely NO CLOUD Services.

---

### Preferred but not Required:

Account System, so that you can add a friend and they always have access to a shared folder If your online.

Doesn't Install Background Services that have to be manually turned on and off, to enable/disable sharing (For example I don't want folders shared if the Program isn't open)

---

#### End Notes:

I will State one last time to be Absolutely clear, I do not want Anything to do with The cloud. And I Do not Want Autosync-ing.

PS: I know there is a program That supports all this out there (well except the image previews) Because I used it in the past (Before the Cloud). Sadly I cannot remember the name of it.

Comment: Full ack to the "no cloud" :) What OSes are involved (or should be covered)? Must it be free, or are you open to pay (how much)? Is a self-hosted web service an option (I think of *ownCloud* here which would mean no *extra* running service if there's a web server already running)? Other names coming to my mind: [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) / [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com/) (cross-platform), [Seafile](http://seafile.com/).

Comment: There is no Web Server running. Basically all I am looking for is an ftp, that can handle thumbnails, at the bare minimum. The PC's involved are Windows 7 and Windows XP.  
I would Use BitTorrent Sync But that doesn't support Image/Video Thumbnails I don't Believe.