# Backup and sync few important files to cloud

Tags: backup, windows-10, file-synchronization, cloud-storage, privacy

I have some important files that I would like to backup to the cloud. These files include work related things (such as resume and job contracts) and the password safe for Keepass. Sometimes I need these on different devices, for example I need the password safe to be able to log into a website on my laptop. I have been using the Dropbox app and saving all these files to a folder it syncs.

I have two problems with Dropbox 1) it randomly starts even though I set it not to. It's really important for me to control when the app starts and syncs 2)  The latest version seems to cause instability issues with my Windows 10 computer. Also I've grown a bit skeptical what large companies such as Microsoft do with personal data so I don't really want to use something like One Drive (Dropbox was nice as it was the only product they had which clearly limits the scope of my data they have).

I don't care if it's not SUPER secure, as I manually encrypt really important things before syncing them anyway.
What alternatives are there to Dropbox? I have red [Alternatives to Google Drive with emphasis on privacy and user experience?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/alternatives-to-google-drive-with-emphasis-on-privacy-and-user-experience?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but many of the answers are outdated as the company no longer exists!

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to personal preferences. Due to your wish to *secure your data*, I am going to suggest you invest in [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) (I have no experience with [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) so I cannot recommend).

There are a few reasons I suggest running OwnCloud over other 'secure' services ([SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) and [Mega](https://mega.nz/) as two alternatives), and they are (not limited to):

- [Cross platform support](https://owncloud.org/install/#install-clients) (Windows 7/8/10, Linux and OSX) - not to mention Web;
- [Scaling applications](https://marketplace.owncloud.com/) integrating to service;

If you are worried about the security involved, take the following [exert](https://owncloud.org/blog/how-owncloud-uses-encryption-to-protect-your-data/):

> For storing data encrypted on ownCloud, you need to have the ownCloud
>   Encryption app enabled. It will then encrypt all your data with a
>   strong, randomly generated key, which is then protected with your
>   log-in password.

Documentation on enabling this is [here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/user_manual/files/encrypting_files.html). Further *general* documentation is as follows:

- [Installing the Desktop Synchronization Client](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/latest/installing.html) and;
- [Installing the Desktop Synchronization Client](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/latest/installing.html#installation-wizard)

Further documentation for security: [Prevent brute force attacks against OwnCloud](https://blog.monotok.org/prevent-brute-force-attacks-against-owncloud/).

If you are going down the route of OwnCloud, I'd suggest implementing a Raspberry Pi. Documentation on configuring it can be found as follows:

- [How to setup a Raspberry Pi Cloud Server](https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-owncloud-server/) and;
- [Create your own Cloud server on Raspberry Pi with OwnCloud](https://www.stewright.me/2017/08/create-cloud-server-raspberry-pi-owncloud/)

---

If you do not want to house the server yourself, there are a number of alternate solutions at your disposal. For example, using [7Zip](https://info.nrao.edu/computing/guide/file-access-and-archiving/7zip/7z-7za-command-line-guide) in unison with [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/drive/):

```
# Script Variables
$Usr = $env:USERNAME
$GC = "C:\$Usr\Google Drive"


# User Variables
$PwD = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Encryption Password"
$Files = Read-Host "Enter UNC Path"


7z.exe a -r -tzip -mx5 "$GC\$Usr-Arc.zip" $Files
```

(Just check the syntax, the abovementioned could be wrong)

Of course, there are other tools you can use in unison with Google Drive:

- [Box Crypt](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/);
- [CryptBox](https://github.com/joskulj/cryptbox) or;
- [EncFS](https://github.com/vgough/encfs) (Find the windows variant if you need it)

---

**Related Questions**

The following questions are loosely related to your question:

- [Encrypt then sync your files to ANY cloud storage as secured offsite backup?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23003/encrypt-then-sync-your-files-to-any-cloud-storage-as-secured-offsite-backup)
- [Secure Folder Share, Without Cloud, or Forced Sync! That supports Thumbnail Previews](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30409/secure-folder-share-without-cloud-or-forced-sync-that-supports-thumbnail-prev)
- [Privacy-minded cloud provider](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37088/privacy-minded-cloud-provider)
- [Self-Hosted Cloud Storage](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42749/self-hosted-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows 10 and you're encrypting important files I'd still recommend OneDrive since the sync client is already installed on every Win10 machine.

Microsoft recently published a useful new resource about how they are (not) using the data of their customers: [Microsoft Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/privacy/you-own-your-data)

If that's not an option you probably should look into self-hosted services like [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/) or [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/).

Answer (score -1):

AJC Sync will let you sync to different cloud locations such as Dropbox or Onedrive and you can have manual control if you want or do it on a schedule.  You can see exactly what will happen to your files and have complete control.  Also there is the option to encrypt files during that process so if the cloud was hacked your files would not be readable.

Its better than the auto cloud sync programs because you have complete control and can backup different folders to different locations rather than having just one folder on your computer synced with the cloud.

It also has built in diff so you can see what has changed in the files etc.
See [AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)