# Self-Hosted Cloud Storage

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a self-hosted cloud storage solution, that:

- Is gratis and open-source
- Has a Windows sync client, that:

  - Runs in the background
  - Supports editing the documents while being offline
  - Preferably integrates with Office 2016 (like OneDrive)
- Has a web UI, that:

  - Supports browsing, creating, uploading and deleting files
  - Supports real-time collaboratively editing documents (.docx) and presentations (.pptx)
- Supports WebDAV
- Has LDAP-based authentication
- Runs fine on a Raspberry Pi 3 with 5 concurrent users
- Fits on a 2 GB SD card (including the OS (Raspbian) and all dependencies)

Comment: Too lazy to write an answer, but as a suggestion: Does NextCloud fit your needs? (There are some addons for the web app, so you may have to install some of them to get some of the features you want)

Comment: @palsch: It doesn't fit on a 2 GB SD card, which I forgot to mention.

Comment: Isn't "self-hosted cloud" an oxymoron?

Comment: @Nakilon not really, given that "cloud" is not the watery thing that stores rain in the sky... Cloud means that it is equally accessible everywhere, and the same as Dropbox hosts a file on a server you can use your own computer to host it.

Comment: @YisroelTech, "equally accessible everywhere" is applicable to practically any service or website.

Answer (score 1):

I have been running a Seafile cloud server from an original pi for over a year now. They support all the requirements that you list with bug fixes and new features being added at regular intervals. [seafile homepage](https://www.seafile.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/). It meets all your requirements. The only thing I would say is you need to be a little patient with ownCloud. If you make an edit to a file, make sure it has synced before making further edits. This is particularly the case when renaming folders.

Comment: "Runs fine on a Raspberry Pi 3 with 5 concurrent users" not much runs fine on a pii. The minute processor gets hot very quick when indexing... so you will have to be patient with whatever you are doing. I heard there is now a cheaper alt. to pi.. banana pi.. like a rasp pi but better

Answer (score 1):

By limiting yourself to 2 GB microSD card you just seriously complicate your life, and even using something like [Alpine Linux](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) won't be sufficient, plus your DB will grow over time, not to mention that you probably might want to allocate some space to swap.

Even 16 GB 10-class cards are dirt-cheap these days, and you are going to have your hands untied and don't worry about dependencies and apt-cache.

Besides, a next iteration of [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) -- the [**Nextcloud**](https://nextcloud.com/) (which I would recommend) -- offers an image for RPi, [NextCloudPi](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/13/nextcloud-ready-raspberry-pi-image/). It is based on Raspbian and has LAMP stack and other goodies included.

Answer (score 0):

Just heard about 'Owncloud'. Free I think with you in charge of users and size. Thats all I know but sounds worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Quick checking shows that owncloud should be able to do what you want.  Then I checked my pi and while I already have some of the dependencies (apache,etc) it only wants to install another 200mb of stuff total, and I could easily get rid of enough of the stuff I have on my pi to get it down to about 1gb used.

But then your problem becomes storage... or do you plan to plug a usb drive into the pi for mass storage?

Comment: Yeah, I'll use an USB drive for mass storage. But can you real-time collaboratively edit documents and presentations in the web UI with such a small installation?