# Looking for a Cloud storage solution with friendly terms of service

Tags: web-apps, cloud-storage

I until recently could store all the images I needed internally, but I've ran out of storage on my phone and want to use a cloud storage solution.

Looking at Google Drive terms of service, I do not want to use Drive as they have the rights to distribute, store for as long as they like, and modify your files. I'm obviously not comfortable with this and I also have qualms over Drive's security.

Hence I'm looking for a Cloud storage solution with more reasonable terms of service. It also has to be free.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: self-hosting, either at home or on a shared hoster, [may be a solution](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42749/9157)...

Comment: Any updates here, Charlie?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow hi Michael, I'm now using Sync.com if I need to cloud store anything as its encrypted on both ends, meaning the company can't even view my pictures let alone sell them or use them to develop AI like Google.

Comment: @Charlie Awesome! Perhaps, make an answer and mark as solved? :)

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow sure thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use a service called Sync.com

Its encrypted at both ends which means that data is much more secure and protected than if using a service such as Drive.

Its also free.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long-winded explanation, but first let's look at Google's [ToS](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2450387?hl=en):

> **How do the Terms of Service affect me?**
>
> As our Terms of Service state, "You retain ownership of any
>   intellectual property rights that you hold in that content. In short,
>   what belongs to you stays yours."
>
> We do not claim ownership in any of your content, including any text,
>   data, information, and files that you upload, share, or store in your
>   Drive account. What our Terms of Service do is enable us to give you
>   the services you want — so if you decide to share a document with
>   someone, or want to open it on a different device, we can provide that
>   functionality.
>
> You control who can access your files in Drive.
>
> We will not share your
>   files and data with others except as described in our Privacy Policy.
>
> We will not change a Private document into a Public one.
>
> We will not use a Private document for marketing or promotional campaigns.
>
> We will keep your data only as long as you ask us to keep it. You can take
>   your data with you if you choose to stop using Google Drive.

Paying particular notice to:

> We will keep your data only as long as you ask us to keep it. You can take
>   your data with you if you choose to stop using Google Drive.

and:

> We do not claim ownership in any of your content, including any text,
>   data, information, and files that you upload, share, or store in your
>   Drive account

I understand you do not like their security concept (but just wanted to clarify it) and their ToS, and '[Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/)'.

---

Refer to my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/45985/9311). If you want to *own* the data, you need to *house* the data. Enter, [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/privacy/).

> **Privacy Policy**
>
> We recognize that privacy is extremely important to our users. We do
>   not share individual user data with third parties without your
>   permission.

Backed up with user access control(s):

> Fine-grained control over access to data and sharing capabilities by
>   user and by group.

As advised, the guts of my reasoning is in my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/45985/9311).

Answer (score 0):

How cloudy do you want? Does it need to be full internet access, or perhaps only at your home or office?

Either way, set up a Linux machine and use synchthing or owncloud or similar.  If you use a VPS you can go inexpensive ($5/mo) but you won't have a lot of storage.  If you go with hardware in your home, you can build a cheap box using software RAID-1 or -5 and have terabytes of storage for not a lot of money.